# how to validate whether the filed allow only numberic values by using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

One of my application for where i have a field that should only allow numeric values, how can i validate this using selenium IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative testing approach - Enter character(s) other than numbers (alpha, special, alphanumeric, etc.) and then ensure your application doesn't process these, or outputs suitable error messages...